# How to obtain the sort matrix of the command sort?

Tags: c, linux, bash, sorting, command

Say, if I have the a file with contents:

```
a1dc3
ab2
ab4c
b3a
ca15d2
...
```

There is at least one integer every line. What I want to do is to sort these lines according to the first integer of each line.

My idea is that we can easily obtain the first integer from each line. And then use command `sort -g` to sort the numeric sequence. I can solve the problem If I know the sort matrix which describe how the `sort` command sort the numeric sequence.

In conclusion, I need a command line utility `qsort` like the one in C program. Once I give the `qsort` a function `compare`, then the sequence can be sorted as what I want.

Is that clear? Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Is the problem really getting the first number?

Comment: I would suggest a short python program would do the easily.

Comment: @doctorlove, the problem is to sort the original sequence by the first number of everyline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this awk-sort-awk pipeline:

```
$ awk -F '[^0-9]*' '{print ($1!=""?$1:$2), $0}' file | sort -n | awk '{$1=""}1'
 a1dc3
 ab2
 b3a
 ab4c
 ca15d2
```

Comment: It's really a good idea to append the keywords to the very begin of the lines. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Extract the number, add it as a prefix, sort, discard the prefix.

```
sed 's/\([^0-9]*\)\([1-9][0-9]*\)/\2 \1\2/' |
sort -n |
cut -d ' ' -f2-
```

This assumes you want an ascending numeric sort on the first sequence of digits on each line, and that all lines contain at least one digit.

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform

Answer (score 3):

In C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

static int intpart(const char *s)
{
    while (*s) {
        if (isdigit((unsigned char)*s)) break;
        s++;
    }
    return atoi(s);
}

static int comp(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    int a = intpart(*(const char **)pa);
    int b = intpart(*(const char **)pb);

    return (a < b) ? -1 : (a > b);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s args\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    qsort(&argv[1], argc - 1, sizeof(char *), comp);
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Run it using:

```
./mysort a1dc3 ab2 ab4c b3a ca15d2
```

or

```
./mysort $(< file)
```

Comment: 35 lines of C, or 1 line of awk. hmmm

Comment: @user000001, I agree, awk wins :)